# EF 5 one to many self referencing - code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, code-first

I have read through a number of one to many self referencing posts but have seen my specific permutation.  If I missed it please post the link.

Here is my scenario.  I have two tables.  Feature contains a collection of Epics, and an Epic can contain a collection of child epics recursively (i can have child child child (n) epic collections).

Below is a simple outline of the type of models I am looking to create.

```
public class Feature
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Epic> Epics { get; set; } 
}

public class Epic
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int FeatureId { get; set; }

    public int ParentEpicId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Epic> ChildEpics { get; set; } 
}
```

I can almost specify the relationships in the modelBuilder but getting hung up on one thing.  The first collection of epics will have a FeatureId FK back to the parent Feature and a null ParentEpicId, but all levels of epic collections below this will have FeatureId set to null and ParentEpicId set to the Id of the parent epic.  (FeatureId could point to the top level feature of the tree of epic children but this is not necessary)

How can I specify this type of relationship in EF code first?

If am not clear or you need more info, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since obviously, both `FeatureId` and `ParentEpicId` map to nullable columns in the database, they need to be mapped to nullable properties in the data model. You should change your `Epic` class to:

```
public class Epic
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? FeatureId { get; set; }

    public int? ParentEpicId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Epic> ChildEpics { get; set; } 
}
```

As for the requirement that exactly one of FeatureId and ParentEpicId must be set, I do not think that there is such a mechanism in EF out of the box.